# How does NumPy Sum (with axis) work?

Tags: python, numpy

I've taken it upon myself to learn how `NumPy` works for my own curiosity.

It seems that the simplest function is the hardest to translate to code (I understand by code). It's easy to hard code each axis for each case but I want to find a dynamic algorithm that can sum in any axis with n-dimensions.
The documentation on the official website is not helpful (It only shows the result not the process) and it's hard to navigate through Python/C code.

**Note:** I did figure out that when an array is summed, the axis specified is "removed", i.e. Sum of an array with a shape of (4, 3, 2) with axis 1 yields an answer of an array with a shape of (4, 2)

Comment: You need to be more specific about what's puzzling you.  What do you mean by 'translate to code'?  As `for i in range...:` kind of expressions?

Comment: @hpaulj Yes I should mention that

Comment: You need to creat an example array, and perform several different iterative summations.  Show your line of thinking.  Then we can suggest improvements.  Forget the psuedo code.

Comment: also your pursuit for getting to know numpy would only be satisfied if you look at actual numpy code and functions - going over `/your-python-installation/Lib/site-packages/numpy` folder contains all the answers to your questions...its a long-term study getting to know how numpy works...lot of times involves knowing python internals

Comment: Most of the `sum` calculation is done in complex compiled code, so the Python code in the site-package directory won't help.

Comment: @hpaulj I figured that out when the "umath" module was a pyd file

Answer (score 93, accepted):

## Setup

consider the numpy array `a`

```
a = np.arange(30).reshape(2, 3, 5)
print(a)

[[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  6  7  8  9]
  [10 11 12 13 14]]

 [[15 16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23 24]
  [25 26 27 28 29]]]
```

---

## Where are the dimensions?

The dimensions and positions are highlighted by the following

```
            p  p  p  p  p
            o  o  o  o  o
            s  s  s  s  s

     dim 2  0  1  2  3  4

            |  |  |  |  |
  dim 0     ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓
  ----> [[[ 0  1  2  3  4]   <---- dim 1, pos 0
  pos 0   [ 5  6  7  8  9]   <---- dim 1, pos 1
          [10 11 12 13 14]]  <---- dim 1, pos 2
  dim 0
  ---->  [[15 16 17 18 19]   <---- dim 1, pos 0
  pos 1   [20 21 22 23 24]   <---- dim 1, pos 1
          [25 26 27 28 29]]] <---- dim 1, pos 2
            ↑  ↑  ↑  ↑  ↑
            |  |  |  |  |

     dim 2  p  p  p  p  p
            o  o  o  o  o
            s  s  s  s  s

            0  1  2  3  4
```

---

## Dimension examples:

This becomes more clear with a few examples

```
a[0, :, :] # dim 0, pos 0

[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]]
```

---

```
a[:, 1, :] # dim 1, pos 1

[[ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
```

---

```
a[:, :, 3] # dim 2, pos 3

[[ 3  8 13]
 [18 23 28]]
```

---

## `sum`

***explanation of `sum` and `axis`***
`a.sum(0)` is the sum of all slices along `dim 0`

```
a.sum(0)

[[15 17 19 21 23]
 [25 27 29 31 33]
 [35 37 39 41 43]]
```

same as

```
a[0, :, :] + \
a[1, :, :]

[[15 17 19 21 23]
 [25 27 29 31 33]
 [35 37 39 41 43]]
```

---

`a.sum(1)` is the sum of all slices along `dim 1`

```
a.sum(1)

[[15 18 21 24 27]
 [60 63 66 69 72]]
```

same as

```
a[:, 0, :] + \
a[:, 1, :] + \
a[:, 2, :]

[[15 18 21 24 27]
 [60 63 66 69 72]]
```

---

`a.sum(2)` is the sum of all slices along `dim 2`

```
a.sum(2)

[[ 10  35  60]
 [ 85 110 135]]
```

same as

```
a[:, :, 0] + \
a[:, :, 1] + \
a[:, :, 2] + \
a[:, :, 3] + \
a[:, :, 4]

[[ 10  35  60]
 [ 85 110 135]]
```

---

default axis is `-1`
this means all axes.  or sum all numbers.

```
a.sum()

435
```

Comment: Thank you! Slice indexing and the visual structure helps a ton and now I can finally map the process in my head.

Comment: @piRSquared ，may i ask which editor do you use to get the picture in section ‘Where are the dimensions’

Comment: @inaMinute I used a markdown cell in Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Very much helpful visualization. One minor change would make it a little more helpful. In the "Dimensions Examples" the first 2 examples have same "dim" and "pos" in ascending order (1st example , dim=pos=0, 2nd example dim=pos=1). When looking at the first time i just assumed the dim has to be same as pos until i looked at the 3rd example. If the dims and pos would have been totally random it would have made me to stop and think at the first pass itself.

Comment: Can you add the case `a.sum ((0,1))` into your explanation? The shape of the result is `5,` (the dimension of the last axis) and the values are `[75, 81, 87, 93, 99]` which is the sum by columns along axis 0 (and also equivalent to `a.sum (axis=(0)).sum (axis=(0))`), Axis 1 is never used, What is the meaning of specifying `axis=(0,1)` in this condition? (Intuitively I expected the sum to be done along axis 2 and to have resulted in a 2x3 array.)

Comment: This is also a good answer: If you do `.sum(axis=n)`, for example, then dimension `n` is collapsed and deleted, with each value in the new matrix equal to the sum of the corresponding collapsed values. For example, if `b` has shape `(5,6,7,8)`, and you do `c = b.sum(axis=2)`, then axis 2 (dimension with size 7) is collapsed, and the result has shape `(5,6,8)`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17079437/2803344

Answer (score 4):

I use a nested loop operation to explain it.

```
import numpy as np

n = np.array(
[[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]],

 [[2, 4, 6],
 [8, 10, 12],
 [14, 16, 18]],

 [[1, 3, 5],
 [7, 9, 11],
 [13, 15, 17]]])

print(n)

print("============ sum axis=None=============")

sum = 0
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3): 
    for k in range(3):
      sum += n[k][i][j]
print(sum) # 216

print('------------------')
print(np.sum(n))  # 216
print("============ sum axis=0 =============") 
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    sum = 0
    for axis in range(3):
      sum += n[axis][i][j]
    print(sum,end=' ')
  print()

print('------------------')
print("sum[0][0] = %d" % (n[0][0][0] + n[1][0][0] + n[2][0][0]))
print("sum[1][1] = %d" % (n[0][1][1] + n[1][1][1] + n[2][1][1]))
print("sum[2][2] = %d" % (n[0][2][2] + n[1][2][2] + n[2][2][2]))
print('------------------')
print(np.sum(n, axis=0)) 
print("============ sum axis=1 =============") 
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    sum = 0
    for axis in range(3):
      sum += n[i][axis][j]
    print(sum,end=' ')
  print()
print('------------------')
print("sum[0][0] = %d" % (n[0][0][0] + n[0][1][0] + n[0][2][0]))
print("sum[1][1] = %d" % (n[1][0][1] + n[1][1][1] + n[1][2][1]))
print("sum[2][2] = %d" % (n[2][0][2] + n[2][1][2] + n[2][2][2]))
print('------------------')
print(np.sum(n, axis=1))  
print("============ sum axis=2 =============") 
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(3):
    sum = 0
    for axis in range(3):
      sum += n[i][j][axis]
    print(sum,end=' ')
  print()
print('------------------')
print("sum[0][0] = %d" % (n[0][0][0] + n[0][0][1] + n[0][0][2]))
print("sum[1][1] = %d" % (n[1][1][0] + n[1][1][1] + n[1][1][2]))
print("sum[2][2] = %d" % (n[2][2][0] + n[2][2][1] + n[2][2][2]))
print('------------------')
print(np.sum(n, axis=2))
print("============ sum axis=(0,1)) =============") 
for i in range(3):
  sum = 0
  for axis1 in range(3):   
    for axis2 in range(3):
      sum += n[axis1][axis2][i]
  print(sum,end=' ')

print()
print('------------------')
print("sum[1] = %d" % (n[0][0][1] + n[0][1][1] + n[0][2][1] +
              n[1][0][1] + n[1][1][1] + n[1][2][1] +
              n[2][0][1] + n[2][1][1] + n[2][2][1] ))
print('------------------')
print(np.sum(n, axis=(0,1)))
```

result：

```
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 7  8  9]]

 [[ 2  4  6]
  [ 8 10 12]
  [14 16 18]]

 [[ 1  3  5]
  [ 7  9 11]
  [13 15 17]]]
============ sum axis=None=============
216
------------------
216
============ sum axis=0 =============
4 9 14 
19 24 29 
34 39 44 
------------------
sum[0][0] = 4
sum[1][1] = 24
sum[2][2] = 44
------------------
[[ 4  9 14]
 [19 24 29]
 [34 39 44]]
============ sum axis=1 =============
12 15 18 
24 30 36 
21 27 33 
------------------
sum[0][0] = 12
sum[1][1] = 30
sum[2][2] = 33
------------------
[[12 15 18]
 [24 30 36]
 [21 27 33]]
============ sum axis=2 =============
6 15 24 
12 30 48 
9 27 45 
------------------
sum[0][0] = 6
sum[1][1] = 30
sum[2][2] = 45
------------------
[[ 6 15 24]
 [12 30 48]
 [ 9 27 45]]
============ sum axis=(0,1)) =============
57 72 87 
------------------
sum[1] = 72
------------------
[57 72 87]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that our array has 2 rows and 3 columns

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,6]])

print(a.shape)
#prints:(2, 3) This array has 2 rows and 3 columns
```

Below are the 3 different possibilities:

```
print(np.sum(a)) #computes sum of all the elements; prints: 19
print(np.sum(a, axis= 0)) #computes sum of all the column; prints: [4 6 9]
print(np.sum(a, axis= 1)) #computes sum of all the rows; prints: [6 13]
```