# confused about sum_axis in mxnet in the tutorial

Tags: mxnet

I am reading the mxnet tutorial on [NDarray part](http://mxnet.io/tutorials/basic/ndarray.html) and I am confused about the use of `sum_axis` function and the example is :

```
>>> a = mx.nd.ones((2,3))
>>> c = mx.nd.sum_axis(a, axis=1)
>>> c.asnumpy()
    array([ 3.,  3.], dtype=float32)
>>> c = mx.nd.sum_axis(a, axis=0)
>>> c.asnumpy()
    array([ 2.,  2.,  2.], dtype=float32)
```

What I am wondering is when the value of paramter `axis` is `1`, I think it should output

```
array([ 2.,  2.,  2.], dtype=float32)
```

but not

```
array([ 3.,  3.], dtype=float32)
```

As when the value of paramter `axis` is `1`, I think the `sum_axis` should compute the sum along the column ,but the result shows it compute the sum along the rows.

And it seems that  `numpy` also compute like this and I really don't understand why this way.
So anyone could explain this ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Numpy has described what axis is in 2D array.  A 2-dimensional array has two corresponding axes: the first running vertically downwards across rows (axis 0), and the second running horizontally across columns (axis 1).

Check the link for example
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/glossary.html
This is also true for MXNet. So, in your example mentioned above:
a = [[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
     [ 1.,  1.,  1.]]

axis 0 means, going vertically downwards. So, it will give you output [2., 2., 2.] and axis 1 means, going horizontally across columns. So, it will give you output [3., 3.]

Comment: Thanks！ That's what I want. But I still have a question that what if there are more than 2 axes.

Comment: I think this visual representation and slicing example will help you understand it in more detail. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40857930/how-does-numpy-sum-with-axis-work